# Calculating revenue share at different tiers

Tags: php, math, range

I'm trying to write a function that can calculate revenue at different tiered levels... For example you sell $10000 worth of widgets. Any earnings from $1 - $999 we take 50%, $1000 - $4999 we take 25%, $5000 - $9999 we take 10%, $10000 - $19999 5%.

The percentage is not taken based on the final value. So if you earned $10000 you don't just fall into the 10% column. Your first $1000 is subject to 50%, the next $5000 25%, the next $4000 10%.

Thanks in advance.

**Final working code. Thanks for the help!

```
    $input = 10000;

    $tiers = array('1000' => .5, '5000' => .25, '10000' => .1, '20000' => .05, '22000' => .01);

    $accounted_for = 0;
    $total_share = 0;

    $tier = each($tiers);
    while($accounted_for < $input) {

        $cutoff = $tier[0];
        $percent = $tier[1];

        $level = (min($cutoff, $input) - $accounted_for) * $percent;

        $total_share += $level;

        $accounted_for = $cutoff;

        $tier = each($tiers);
    }

    return $total_share;
```

Comment: what language? Please post the code, you have written so far.

Comment: See above, using code from poster below

Comment: That should be "$accounted_for += $cutoff"

Comment: Thats not the problem. The problem is $cutoff, $input) - $accounted_for. At the second tier (5000) its turning it into 4000.

Comment: It should be 4000 - it's 4000 from the cutoff of the first tier (1000) to the cutoff of the second tier (5000). Since the first tier has already had the first rate applied (it's already in $total_share), you don't want to multiply the second rate by the 5000 cutoff, but instead by the 4000 difference.

Comment: Oh, also - your if-else statement is unnecessary. The min() call takes care of both cases (whether the input is less than or greater than the cutoff).

Comment: I got myself all confused (its late). Did the math wrong on paper, changed the code to reflect that. I reverted my changes and everything looks good now. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't specified a language, here's some pseudocode:

```
input = 99999

tiers = [list of (%,cutoff) tuples]

accounted_for = 0
total_share = 0

while accounted_for is less than input:
    percent,cutoff = next element of tiers
    total_share += (min(cutoff,input) - accounted_for) * percent
    accounted_for = cutoff

return total_share
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I implemented your suggestion. But I think I'm off still...

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is how the IRS tax code works, except the IRS gets more the more you make.  In this model the commission slides down the more you sell.  I am assuming you want the answer in PHP since you put it in the PHP category.  If you wanted to have different schedules for different sales people you could make the tiers array an argument for the function.

```
function calculateEarnings($grossAmountSold) {
    $earnings = 0;
    $accountedFor = 0;
    $tiers = array('1000' => .5, '5000' => .25, '10000' => .1, '20000' => .05, '22000' => .01);

    while($accountedFor < $grossAmountSold) {
        list($cutoff, $commissionRate) = each($tiers);
        if($grossAmountSold < $cutoff) {
            $sold = $grossAmountSold - $accountedFor;
        } else {
            $sold = $cutoff - $accountedFor;
        }
        $earnings += $sold * $commissionRate;
        $accountedFor += $cutoff;
    }
    return $earnings;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your contribution. It's not exactly what I was looking for. Yours takes a cut at each level. The solution from Dav accounts for previous tiers. Thanks again.