# Convert tax like IRS function to SQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Trying to convert this tax-like IRS function [Calculating revenue share at different tiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817920/calculating-revenue-share-at-different-tiers) to SQL. The assumption is the table would be one column (price) and the tiers will be added dynamically.

My first attempt has some case statements that didn't work out well. I have since scrapped it :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

SQL isn't really suited to iterative loops. I'd

```
select * from `brackets` where `tier` < $income
```

From there I'd... well, you linked to some sample code in another language yourself. You should really do it that way.

If you insist otherwise, SQL can do it:

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure `calcTax`(IN v_param1 int)

begin
declare v_tier int;
declare v_rate decimal(3,3);
declare v_untaxed int default 0;
declare v_taxTotal float default 0;

set v_untaxed = v_param1;
set v_taxTotal = 0;

while v_untaxed > 0 do
select max(`tier`), max(`rate`) into v_tier, v_rate
    from `brackets` where tier < v_untaxed order by `tier` desc limit 1;

set v_taxTotal = v_taxTotal + (v_untaxed - v_tier) * v_rate;
set v_untaxed = v_tier;
end while;

select v_taxTotal;
end;
$$
```

Correct datatypes are up to you. You'll need a tax brackets table that works out. I made one for testing below (with poorly advised data types).

```
create table brackets (tier int primary key, rate float);
insert into brackets values (0, 0), (10000, 0.1), (50000, 0.2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is definitely a step in the right direction. I was hoping to be able to run this on a table that has rows of values (prices, or whatever). The tiers would be dynamic and passed in with the query. This appears to take the opposite approach?

Comment: I would then suggest that you handle this by creating a temporary table that has the values you seek and passing the table name as a second parameter to the query. You should be able to take what I've got and work that up from there. I'm very curious why you're doing this with such a focus on the database being the calculation workhorse.

Comment: I ended up sticking with the in code version. You were right and it made the most sense. I appreciate your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a MYSQL user defined function. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-functions.html

Comment: Think its possible to do with straight SQL and without a user defined function?